# amazon s3 video files accessible only from my domain/server?

Tags: amazon-s3

Now, I know that I cannot stop someone from downloading my videos and sharing, however I would prefer to have it to so that people do not copy paste links directly to my bucket. Thus, is there a way to make my bucket accessible only from my server/domain making the request?

If it helps, I'm using jwplayer which loads from a xml playlist that has all the links. This playlist definitely can be opened and viewed from anywhere and is where I expect the easy copy and paste comes from.

I don't want to mask the urls because that means my bucket is readable to everyone. There is probably some chance that someone will find the url of my bucket and the name of the files and connect everything together...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible by [Using Bucket Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html), which allows you to *define access rights for Amazon S3 resources* - there are a couple of [Example Cases for Amazon S3 Bucket Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html) illustrating the functionality, and amongst these you'll find an example for *Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses* as well:

> This statement grants permissions to any user to perform any S3 action
>   on objects in the specified bucket. However, the request must
>   originate from the range of IP addresses specified in the condition.

Depending on the specifics of your use case, a bucket policy for this might look like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*" 
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition" : {
                "IpAddress" : {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.168.143.0/24" 
                },
                "NotIpAddress" : {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.168.143.188/32" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    ]
}
```

As shown the `aws:sourceIp` value for parameters `IPAddress` and `NotIpAddress` is expressed in [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation), enabling respective flexibility for composing the desired scope.

Finally, you might want to check out the recommended [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html), select type *S3 Bucket Policy* and explore the available *Actions* and *Conditions* to compose more targeted policies for your use case eventually - the documentation for [Conditions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) explains this in detail.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, just wondering, instead of a ip address, can I make it from a domain name? Turns out I have to pay monthly to get a unique ip for my shared hosting...

Comment: @Ali: I'm afraid this is not available as such (despite being an obvious use case indeed); I've updated the closing paragraphs of my answer regarding the CIDR notation in use for `aws:sourceIp` as well as other conditions available and explorable via the [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) - the former might allow you to specify all IP address blocks your provider might be using (if documented), thus reducing the hot linking surface considerably already. Whether this is feasible at all depends on your use case and environment (i.e provider) of course.

Comment: See the arulraj.net's answer for domain specific permissions. I know this is two years later, but this comment through off my search so I thought I'd update it.

Answer (score 7):

The Ip address will help if your server going to access your bucket. But JWPlayer is from client side. So the request is directly goes from jwplayer(browser) to s3 bucket url, Not via your server. In this case "referrer bucket policy" will help you in this.

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "1",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketname/*",
    "Condition": {
      "StringNotLike": {
        "aws:Referer": [
          "http://yoursitename.com/*",
          "http://*.yoursitename.com/*"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

So now s3 will allow if that request come from your site only.

Comment: If anyone sends a request by setting referrer header then I that case he will easily download a video.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your bucket protected, which is by default the way it is. (meaning you only have access to objects in it)  Then you can request files from Amazon S3 from your website and give it a time limit to which the user can see it.

```
//set time so that users can see file for 1 minute. then it is protected again.
$response = $s3->get_object_url(YOUR_A3_BUCKET, PATH/TO/FILE, '1 minutes');
```

This will automatically give you a url that has parameters associated with it which only is accessible for 1 minute.  You can use that as your source within your website and then they could not copy and paste it into the browser after that 1 minute.

You can read more about this at the [Amazon SDK for PHP](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_url)

Comment: Can this be done on a bucket level? e.g. get a signed url for all files in a bucket to expire after XX, instead of needing to request this for each and every URL at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer

Suppose you have a website with domain name (www.example.com or example.com) with links to photos and videos stored in your Amazon S3 bucket, examplebucket. By default, all the Amazon S3 resources are private, so only the AWS account that created the resources can access them. To allow read access to these objects from your website, you can add a bucket policy that allows s3:GetObject permission with a condition, using the aws:referer key, that the get request must originate from specific webpages. The following policy specifies the StringLike condition with the aws:Referer condition key.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is stumbling upon this now, please take note that Amazon has changed the JSON format for the bucket policies and now requires each allowed / denied IP or domain to be listed separately. See below for an example.

Either way, I strongly recommend to use the [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to make sure your formatting is correct.

AWS S3 Bucket Policy - Allow Access only from multiple IPs

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1618636210012",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1618635877058",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/folder/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "333.444.555.666"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1618636151833",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/folder/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "222.333.444.555"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1618636203591",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/folder/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "111.222.333.444"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```